# How to cope with unreachable DB server with JDBC

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I've got a Java application that communicates with a DB server. Autocommit mode needs to be set to false, so there's a scheduled task that performs the commit once per second:

I'm trying to avoid data loss if such server is temporarily unreachable from my app.

```
    Connection stableConn = ...;
    stableConn.setAutoCommit(false);

    //create the task to commit changes every second:
    commitTask = new Timer("CommitOnDB");
    commitTask.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean exit = false;

            //if the connection to DB is lost, loop until it is re-established:
            while(!exit) {
                try {
                    stableConn.commit();    
                    exit = true;
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    exit = !"08007".equals(e.getSQLState());
                    log.error("Cannot commit statements due to " + e + ";state=" + e.getSQLState(), e);
                }
            }
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
```

I tried to catch the 08007 SQLState when connection goes down, but anyway, at the second round of the loop, I get another Exception stating the connection is already closed.

Moreover, I'd like to have a code that works fine for different DBMS, like MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.

Can anyone point me on the right direction?

Comment: "*so there's a scheduled task that performs the commit once per second*" that sounds ***terribly*** wrong. You should commit when your transaction is done. The way you do it, you can also just enable auto-commit.

Comment: 08007 is the sqlstate defined in the SQL standard as 'transaction resolution unknown`. Most connection pools will treat that as an unrecoverable error and close the connection. Also most servers will rollback a transaction if the connection was lost.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it depends on the task. What if he is processing some batch work, like inserting bulk records - committing too often is ineffective, not committing at all is ineffective too, so he commits after some periods of time.

Comment: I think you should again get the connection.

Comment: @AlexKreutznaer it is exactly as you said: we have a huge amount of little operations that should be performed one by one. I can get the connection again, but how to replay the statements prepared with the old connection? is there a way to set the new connection in place of the old one directly in the prepared statement, or should I recreate it?

Comment: @CristianoGhersi Your uncommitted data will be lost.  What you need is a robust recovery mechanism. I don't know where you take the bulk records from. For example you take text files from a folder and extract data from the files. If a file is successfully processed - delete it from the folder. If at some point the connection is lost - you will NOT process and NOT delete the file. Next time when you scan the folder you will pick it up again. It depends on the detail. But I guess you do something like that.

Comment: @CristianoGhersi  another thing which may add robustness to your mechanism - using MERGE instead of INSERT. If the record is already inserted it will be updates. But maybe you don't need such behavior.

Comment: @AlexKreutznaer so, it seems that the only way is to save somewhere my data until they are committed: perhaps I can save in a queue the prepared statements that have been executed until the commit arrives: if the commit succeeds, I clear the queue, otherwise I recreate a connection and re-play the statements in the queue.. what do you think about this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Add some check like this:

```
if(stableConn.isClosed()) {
    stableConn = getRecoveredConnection();
}
```

Or

```
if(!SomeHelper.isValid(connection)) {
   ... 
}
```

You even actually better do it in catch or finally, because some SQL exceptions just tell you that the databse doesn't like you operation, where as others (as in your case) invalidate the session.